# IPv6 connectivity through IPv4 using OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, ipv4, tunnel

I've set up a Debian-based server at home, which handles dhcp and a bunch of other services. Unfortunately, even though the machine is capable of using IPv6, my ISP doesn't support it. I was wondering if it's possible to route the ipv6 traffic from my network to an external server.

I've revived one of my retired servers that is good to go with both protocols. It has two public addresses assigned to it, I'm also including routes that are set up.

```
inet addr:86.XX.XX.190  Bcast:86.XX.XX.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

default via 86.XX.XX.1 dev eth0
86.XX.XX.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 86.XX.XX.190


inet6 addr: 2a03:XXXX:10:abe::1/64 Scope:Global

2a03:XXXX:10:abe::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

As I said before, those addresses are public.

I've already set up an OpenVPN on the external server and connected my home server to it as a client, using only IPv4. Works just fine, both machines can ping each other in the created network.

What I'd like to achieve is using this external server to handle ipv6 traffic from my home. I believe that is possible, isn't it? I have no clue on how to approach this, as ipv6 seems really complicated. Any kind of help would be appreciated. I have to admit that I'm in a hurry to get this working so I'm going to post this to openvpn forums too, I hope you don't mind.

Cheers!